# How do I prevent my style from being overridden another style on a surrounding div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

It seems elementary, but here is problem.

Stylesheet like so:

```
#Content h1, #Content h2, #Content h3, #Content h4, #Content h5, #Content h6 {
  color: #405679;
}

h3#issueHeader {
  color: blue;
}
```

HTML like so:

```
<div id="Content">
  <h3 id="issueHeader">In This Issue:</h3>
</div>
```

Instead of my issueHeader selector overriding the Content selector like I would expect, Firebug and my eyeballs show me that the color is inherited from the div, and the *issueHeader* selector is overridden. Hunh?

Comment: Google "CSS selector specificity" or some such. Or have a quick look at http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. CSS is not my strong point. Zack, I upvoted you for being first, but I picked dnagirl because her answer gave a little more explanation as to why this is so.

Comment: Re RegDwight - I asked The Google first, but sometimes it is hard to find the specific answer you are looking for in the mountain of responses. That link is a great resource though, thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`CSS` gives more weight to styles with more [specific](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) selectors. So if you want `#Content h3` not to override `h3#issueHeader`, give it another selector: e.g. #Content h3#issueHeader

If your h1...hx elements are meant to be generally #405679, set them to that without the #Content selector. Then override them with a more specific selector when you need to.

**However**, because the way weight is calculated, we need to use **closest** element/class in our selector to get enough-weight, for example:

- Consider we want to style "`z`" element.
- But our style is overridden by "`y z`" selector (without quotes).
- Even if our selector is more specific:

  - Starting from "`a b c`" all the way to "`u v w`" (without `x`).
  - We can't get more wight than "`y z`".
  - But "`x y z`" selector will have enough weight (as x-tagged-element is parent of y-tagged-element).

Answer (score 55):

You can throw the `!important` attribute on `h3#issueHeader` to force the browser to use that style

```
h3#issueHeader {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

However, it is only partially supported in IE6

---

Additionally, this should only be used as a last resort to the other solutions purposed.  This is because if users of your website want to override your style, important becomes a useful tool for that.

Comment: Using the !important should only be a last resort. In this case, using a more specific selector works also.

Comment: @Zack - Thanks for that; I wasn't sure why it ought not to be used and did some googling.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Zack why should it be a last resort.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid see the article mentioned above.

Comment: It is indeed a last resort for me, I am trying to customize the styling of `ngx-markdown` . It only allows you to add prefix to the existing css name for `code` element for your custom styling which is anyways overridden by its own. 
` !important ` is a life saver here. :)

Comment: This should be the correct answer, esp. with regards to how the question is worded. It is common for themes and platforms to add :not(:whatever) flags on their stylesheets that you can't not include so it's the only practical solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the selector as:

```
#Content h3#issueHeader {
    color: blue;
}
```

This should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If id="issueHeader" is duplicated that could do it.

Comment: I assume you mean if it is used in more than one style? Nope, I am not doing that. It is a very small stylesheet, so it's easy to check.

Answer (score 1):

You are having what's called CSS specificity.  Here's a good writup (using starwars to boot), that explains the basics in terms of points and how to calculate what will cascade:

http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: broken link -- please fix

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Shadow DOM** which will add a complete encapsulation to your element and then it will not be affected by any global styles.
You can find more about that in this article : https://bitsofco.de/what-is-the-shadow-dom/