# Why chrome devtools showing this?Body color is not working

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

why body color is not working?

[image]

and i am seeing this in devtools . the problem is marked on the picture.

Comment: Because it's overridden by the default `a:-webkit-any-link` rule.

Answer (score 1):

This is no bug. The body color is overwritten by something else, as wOxxOm pointed out. You might wanna take a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196511/how-do-i-prevent-my-style-from-being-overridden-another-style-on-a-surrounding-d).

Either you use the `!important` attribute in your CSS or give the specific part you want colored a more specific selector. The CSS styles priorities decline from specific to general.

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution . just written this as base `a{color:red}`